# HIVE: How to sum values from key/value strings by key

Tags: string, hive, key-value

I've got two `string` columns containing `key/value` pairs variables. Something like this:

```
    column1         column2
a:1,b:2,c:3         a:5,c:3
   a:12,b:4     a:9,b:3,d:5
```

How can I sum those values (in real life I don't know how many keys I have, some keys can be found only in one column) by specific key to get this:

```
         column12
  a:6,b:2,c:6,d:0
 a:21,b:7,c:0,d:5
```

or this:

```
 a  b  c  d
 6  2  6  0
21  7  0  5
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each row has a unique identifier "id", this below query
 should work.

```sql
select id, collect_list(CONCAT(key,':',val)) as column12  
from  
(  
  select id, key, SUM(val) as val  
  from  
  (  
    select id, k1 as key, k2 as key, v1 as val, v2 as val  
    from  
    (  
      select id, str_to_map(col1,',',':') as c1, str_to_map(col2,',',':') as c2  
      from table  
    )x  
    LATERAL VIEW explode(c1) e1 as k1,v1  
    LATERAL VIEW explode(c2) e2 as k2,v2  
  )y  
)z
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is by writing a custom mapreduce code using Hcatalog.

The following MR takes input columns of table 1 and writes the resultant column into the table2  (reducer is not necessary as the logic is handled in the mapper)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.common.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.*;
import org.apache.hcatalog.data.schema.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class HCatSum extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class Map
            extends
            Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, WritableComparable, HCatRecord> {
        String column1;
        String column2;
        String val;

        @Override
        protected void map(
                WritableComparable key,
                HCatRecord value,
                org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<WritableComparable, HCatRecord, WritableComparable, HCatRecord>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            column1 = (String) value.get(0); // a:1,b:2,c:3
            column2 = (String) value.get(1); // a:5,c:3

            String colArray[] = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(
                    column1.split(","), column2.split(","));
            HashMap<String, Integer> hs = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (String token : colArray) {
                String tokensplit[] = token.split(":");
                String k = tokensplit[0];
                int v = Integer.parseInt(tokensplit[1]);
                if (hs.containsKey(k)) {
                    int prev = hs.get(k);
                    hs.put(k, prev + v);
                } else {
                    hs.put(k, v);                       
                }
            }

            val = Arrays.toString(hs.entrySet().toArray()); // [a=6,b=2,c=6]
            HCatRecord record = new DefaultHCatRecord(1);
            record.set(0, val);
            context.write(null, record);
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();

        // Get the input and output table names as arguments
        String inputTableName = args[0];
        String outputTableName = args[1];
        // Assume the default database
        String dbName = null;

        Job job = new Job(conf, "HCatsum");
        HCatInputFormat.setInput(job,
                InputJobInfo.create(dbName, inputTableName, null));
        job.setJarByClass(HCatSum.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

        // An HCatalog record as input
        job.setInputFormatClass(HCatInputFormat.class);

        // Mapper emits a string as key and an integer as value
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(WritableComparable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class);

        // Ignore the key for the reducer output; emitting an HCatalog record as
        // value

        job.setOutputKeyClass(WritableComparable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(DefaultHCatRecord.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(HCatOutputFormat.class);

        HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job,
                OutputJobInfo.create(dbName, outputTableName, null));
        HCatSchema s = HCatOutputFormat.getTableSchema(job);
        System.err.println("INFO: output schema explicitly set for writing:"
                + s);
        HCatOutputFormat.setSchema(job, s);
        return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new HCatSum(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

How to run MR with  HCatalog (reference link):
[Hive Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+InputOutput)

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.  It's a bit of a hack but will work regardless of the number of keys you have.

**udf0.py**

```
#/usr/bin/python

import sys
from collections import Counter

for line in sys.stdin:
    words = line.strip().split('\t')
    c = Counter()

    for word in words:
        d = {}
        s = word.split(',')
        for ss in s:
            k,v = ss.split(':')
            d[k] = int(v)

        c.update(d)

    print ','.join([str(k)+':'+str(v) for k,v in dict(c).iteritems()])
```

**udf1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    w0, w1 = line.strip().split('\t')

    out = {}
    d = {}
    l = []

    s0 = w0.strip().split(',')
    s1 = w1.strip().split(',')

    for ss in s0:
        k,v = ss.split(':')
        d[k] = int(v)

    for ss in s1:
        l.append(ss)

    for keys in l:
        if d.get(keys, None) is not None:
            out[keys] = d[keys]
        else:
            out[keys] = 0

     print ','.join([str(k)+':'+str(v) for k,v in out.iteritems()])
```

**Hive Query**:

```
add file /home/username/udf0.py;
add file /home/username/udf1.py;

SELECT TRANSFORM(dict, unique_keys)
       USING 'python udf1.py'
       AS (final_map STRING)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT dict
    , CONCAT_WS(',', unique_keys) as unique_keys
  FROM (
    SELECT dict
      , COLLECT_SET(keys) OVER () AS unique_keys
    FROM (
      SELECT dict
        , keys
      FROM (
        SELECT dict
          , map_keys(str_to_map(dict)) AS key_arr
        FROM (
          SELECT TRANSFORM (col1, col2)
                 USING 'python udf0.py'
                 AS (dict STRING)
          FROM db.tbl ) x ) z
      LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(key_arr) exptbl AS keys ) a ) b ) c
```

**Output:**

```
a:6,b:2,c:6,d:0
a:21,b:7,c:0,d:5
```

**Explaination:**

The first UDF will take your string, convert it to a python dictionary and update the keys (i.e. add the values with matching keys together).  Since you don't know the actual keys, you'll know need to extract the keys from each dictionary (`map_keys()` in the hive query), explode the table, and then collect them back into a unique set.  Now, you'll have all the possible keys in any dictionary.  Then from there, you can use the second UDF to import the dictionary created in the first UDF, check if each key is present, and if not, put a zero for it's value.